# Call to MySQL user defined function in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, mysql-routines

I'm working on cakePHP 3. I have a user defined function(UDF or Routine) in mysql database. That function takes two parameters and returns an integer value. I have to match that returned value in MySQL where clause.

I know mysql query to use that function. i.e,

```
SELECT customer_id FROM table_name WHERE routine_name(param1, param2)=1;    //param1 is 'customer_id' which I have written after SELECT
```

But I don't know that how to build this query in cakePHP 3. If anyone knows the solution, answer will be appreciate.

Here is my cakePHP 3 code.

```
$purchasesTable = TableRegistry::get("Purchases");
$query = $purchasesTable->find();

$fields = ['customer_id'];
$query->select($fields);
$query->where(
    //    Routine/Function call should be here as per MySQL query.
    //    So, I think here I have to do something.
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution.. Here it is.

```
$abc = $query->func()->function_name(['param1' => 'literal']);
$query->where(function ($exp) use ($abc) {
        return $exp->gt($abc, 14);
    });
```